# What is the order of NPCs in terms of acquiring them?

Tags: terraria

For example, if a player had all the necessary requirements for every NPC that needed requirements without finding them. (For example if you downloaded a custom map with lots of houses and no NPCs and a character with a gun explosives 50 silver has heart crystals etc) what would be the order that they come?

I believe it starts with Guide, Merchant, Nurse but then I'm not sure. If possible could I have the full list (Guide to Cyborg).

P.S If they don't have an order thats OK too but I think they do

Comment: Yes, but i am asking for the list and not the requirements, i know the requirements already and i am looking the full list not the first five

Comment: That's exactly what that question is asking about

Comment: That one only has 7 npc's though. i need the full list please

Comment: Normally I would suggest opening a bounty for more info on the linked question, but as you're new I think you did the right thing. As long as you differentiate it (maybe edit it to specifically lean on *order without regard to requirements*) I think you're fine.

Comment: If the full list isn't there, that's an argument for updating it.  Since it's already been asked, though, I'm voting to close.

Comment: @RobertWertz I still don't see how this question is not a duplicate of the linked question, regardless of your suggestion

Comment: Fair point, it is a duplicate of a question that hasn't been fully answered, I just am not sure what the alternative for a new member would have been. It's not like he can comment or post a bounty on the linked question to draw attention to the incomplete answer. Yes marking this as duplicate is the right answer, I'm just looking for what to tell the asker the next time something like this comes up.

Comment: While I understand that people like to use StackExchange for question/answer type stuff, but why would you (@Opalmine) not bother looking at the wiki for something like this? http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC. This tells you everything you need to do. That other question this one is supposedly a duplicate of is ridiculously out of date, too.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make too much sense as you can't have all the requirements without having any of them, since a good portion of the NPCs are acquired once you find them on the map. Others have a requirement to have a certain number of other NPC's.

The Nurse and Demolitionist have a requirement of having the Merchant.

The Painter has a requirement of having 8 other town NPCs and the Party Girl has a chance of spawning after having 14 other NPCs.

The Stylist, Angler, Goblin Tinkerer, Mechanic, Wizard all need to be found and talked to before they will move in.

Comment: Maybe this will help, if i made a house and i had a gun and explosives, which one would come first, the arms dealer or the demolitionist. Or is it random

Comment: @Opalmine http://tconfig.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_Decompile_Terraria look at the source code if you really want to know, to see how the check is done. It would probably be easier to test it. It's likely that the order is the same as this: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC#Town_NPCs but there's no way to tell without looking at the source code

Comment: OK thank you, i think i might just use the npc list from the wiki, usually i use the wikia and that does it in alphabetical order so i came here.

Comment: An easy way to test this is to acquire all the NPC's, then have them all killed in one night. They won't start coming back until the next day and they should return in their proper order.

Comment: @Chippies without looking at the source code you won't know if the respawning is handled differently. To properly test it you would have to inject all the proper data.